how to remove white space in print preview after the footer and fix the footer at the bottom of the page in print preview?
There is a white blank space after the footer in print preview, I want to remove that space and fix my footer at the bottom of the page. I tried this code
 @page {
 size: A4;
 margin: 0;
}
@media print {
   footer {
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 0;
       width: 100%;
   }

This code worked but the text is printed twice and overlap each other

@media print {
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden; /* Add this line */
    }
}

